# possible to select multiple options with xpath?

Tags: xpath, nokogiri

```
/html/body/form/select/option[@val = '1' and @val = '3']
```

so that means select the first and third option in a select-multiple form ?

Comment: seems you just need to change your logical operator; @val cant be 1 AND 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you mean `or`?

```
/html/body/form/select/option[@val = '1' or @val = '3']
```

That should select both elements.  By using `and` you're trying to select an element whose `val` is both `1` and `3`, which isn't going to work. :-)

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, by select you mean it returns those nodes in the results, right? Not actually selects it in the DOM?

Either way, what you want is the following:

```
 /html/body/form/select/option[1|3]
```

or

```
 /html/body/form/select/option[position()=1|postion()=3]
```

Notice the use of the `|` meaning "or", you don't want to use "and" because that means you want all results that are **both** in position 1 and 3, which is impossible. You want all results that are in **either** position 1 or 3.

Answer (score 0):

Almost. A predicate (everything inside the square brackets) specifies the condition for including a specific node in the result set, and it's impossible for any one element to have a `val` value of 1 *and* 3 at the same time. If you replace the `and` with `or`, however, the expression will match any node that meets either criteria:

`/html/body/form/select/option[@val = '1' or @val = '3']`

A side note: If you want to select nodes based on their position and not their attribute values, you can use the `position()` function inside the predicate.